# I am unable to stage changes in VSCode

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have a file in VSCode. I have edited it multiple times and pressed ctrl+s to save it. All the changes end up in the staging area, but when I press stage, nothing happens. I have also tried to commit these unstaged changes, all with no luck.

Comment: May you try using the command line to rule out that first?

Comment: If you open the "Output" tab in the bottom pane, there should be a `Git` option in the upper-right. Check to see if you're getting any errors in there.

Comment: I had same issue only when I was clicking minified files(eg min.css, min.js etc) which and then clicking stage files and nothing happened. The reason for that was because vs code was running in the background trying first to open these big files and until this is done then my files was in staging.

Answer (score 1):

To stage changes when you're ready, select the + (plus) button on each file you want to stage, or right-click a file and then select Stage. You can also stage all your modified files with one click by using the stage all + (plus) button at the top of the Changes section. And after that you can commit and make the changes.